# IF statement validate.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I coded a form with a hidden field, if the user selects "telephone" via radio box, another field is shown.

I need to validate the fields in the form using validate.js, The form and validate were working before I tried with an if statement.

The code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#info_tel').hide(); 
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        if($(this).attr("value")=="2"){
            $("#info_tel").show();
            $("#form1").validate({
                rules: {
                    nombre: "required",
                    apellido1: "required",
                    email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                        },
                    terminos: "required",
                    telefono: "required"
                },
                messages: {
                    nombre: "*Requerido.",
                    apellido1: "*Requerido.",
                    email: "*Requerido.",
                    terminos: "*Requerido."
                }
            });
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="1"){
            $('#info_tel').hide();
            $("#form1").validate({
                rules: {
                    nombre: "required",
                    apellido1: "required",
                    email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                        },
                    terminos: "required"
                },
                messages: {
                    nombre: "*Requerido.",
                    apellido1: "*Requerido.",
                    email: "*Requerido.",
                    terminos: "*Requerido."
                }
            });
        }
    });




});
```

This works, but if I submit the form without clicking the `input[type="radio"]`, it does not validate at all.

Answer (score 0):

I did it. 
The full code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
        $("#form1").validate({
            rules: {
                nombre: "required",
                apellido1: "required",
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                    },
                terminos: "required"
            },
            messages: {
                nombre: "*Requerido.",
                apellido1: "*Requerido.",
                email: "*Requerido.",
                terminos: "*Requerido."
            }
        });

        $('#info_tel').hide(); 
        $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
            if($(this).attr("value")=="2"){
                $("#info_tel").show();
                //tel required
                $( "#telefono" ).rules( "add", {
                  required: true,
                  minlength: 10,
                  messages: {
                    required: "*Requerido.",
                    minlength: jQuery.format("{0} digitos")
                  }
                });
            }
            if($(this).attr("value")=="1"){
                $('#info_tel').hide();
            }
        });
    });
```